# Spark reading file from local and writing in hdfs

Tags: apache-spark

I have one file in local system. 
I want to read it using Spark locally and then write it in HDFS  using the same spark program
Is it possible ?

Comment: are you doing any processing after loading file into spark ?

Comment: no, i just want to read it from local and write in hdfs

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stackoverflow. Please have a look at [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Your current questions is written to be answered with a simple "yes" or "no". (Actually the answer is "yes".) But what now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Client Mode` If you run spark in client mode, Your driver will be running in your local system, so it can easily access your local files & write to HDFS.

In this mode to access your local files try appending your path after `file://<local_path_file>`

`Cluster Mode` If you run spark in cluster mode your driver will be launched from one of the worker, hence you can't access your local files in cluster mode.

```
spark.read.text("file:///tmp/srinivas/hive.log") // To access local files, without file:// It will search in HDFS location.
```