# How to read a local file using pyspark

Tags: pyspark

I have a csv file located in the local folder. Is it possible to read this file data using pyspark? I have used below script but it threw filenotfound exception.

```
df= spark.read.format(“csv”).option(“header”,”true”).load(‘file:///home/file1.csv’)
```

Comment: is the folder accessible from the environment where you're using pyspark? if not, you'd have to map the storage to that env or copy the file(s) to a location accessible to that env.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spark reading file from local and writing in hdfs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61495058/spark-reading-file-from-local-and-writing-in-hdfs)